# Get internet working on Ubuntu server 18.0, surface 3

Tags: networking, server

I'm trying to go about repurposing an old surface 3 computer I have, but I'm having trouble doing network interface setup and such. I'm not sure what steps to take. I got the distro installed and I get a command prompt. I don't have internet access and `ifconfig -a` returns this:

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING> mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop txqueuelen 1000 (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 616 bytes 43864 (43.8 KB)
        RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
        TX packets 616 bytes 43864 (43.8 KB)
        TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0 

wlp1s0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        ether <some address> txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 KB)
        RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
        TX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 KB)
        TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
```

My `/etc/network/interfaces` looks like this:

```
auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlo1
iface wl1 inet static
address 192.168.1.12
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
wpa-ssid <network name>
wpa-psk <passkey>
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.168.1.1
```

I just don't really know the commands to get things working here. I was able to run `sudo ifconfig wlp1s0 up` with no errors. But I don't really know how to see if it worked.

On a side note, I eventually want to get Emby installed on here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you're mixing NetworkManager/ifup/ifdown and networkd commands, and you've selected the wrong interface. First show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `sudo lshw -C network`.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: What are you needing an update for?? I moved onto a different solution. Thanks for the insight though. I think my hardware might just be bad. Not sure.

Comment: Because I didn't see anywhere that you moved onto a different solution, and because I put together an answer which I think answers your question. See below.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the "ip" commands. Try running "ip addr show". If that command works, try "ip link set wlp1s0 up". You may need to update your interface file from wlo1 to wlp1s0 as they are different.

edited to correct typo

Comment: It says `Object "show" is unknown, try "ip help". I did the second command and it didn't output anything. What should I check after that? How do I know it worked or not?

Comment: Sorry, it's late, "ip addr show"

Comment: No probs, `ip addr show` returned a bunch of stuff... not sure what's relevant..

Comment: copy paste it here

Comment: 1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

3: wlp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <mac address i think> ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Comment: On a side note, when I plug in my ethernet cable and run the command, I get this 2: enx0000000006cd5a: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000 and a similar link/ether as above, with the mac address and such.

Comment: So you don't have any 'eno1' devices or ethernet devices listed. Also, I'm thinking your wlp1s0 isn't coming up because you don't have a configure for it. Why are you using 18 server if I may ask? You could try 18 desktop and do a minimum install with xfce or another lightweight desktop. That way you can remote desktop into the device for config work...

Comment: Yeah I'm doing server because I thought it would be the lightest load on this computer. I'm ok at sshing in and such, so that's not a problem, I just am not a network guy at all, so trying to learn as well as getting it to work.

Comment: Okay, so here is a guide I use to connect to wireless via cli...

https://tutorials.technology/tutorials/How-to-connect-to-Wi-Fi-using-command-line-with-Ubuntu-18_04-.html


give that a try to make sure you have a configuration for the wireless card...

Comment: Is there something I can do to get ethernet working first? I can't really download any packages if there is no internet connection...

Comment: If your wireless card is being seen, you may have the needed packages. Skip the install packages part and follow the setup part. If you run a command and it doesn't work, then you will need to find a USB ethernet dongle that works. You can try rebooting the tablet with the ethernet cable attached (im guessing you have a dock). Once you reboot, run ip addr show. If you have "eth0" "eth1" "eno0" "eno1" or something other than "lo" and the one for the wireless you have ethernet.

Answer (score 0):

**Make /etc/network/interfaces look like this:**

```
auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback
```

**Make your /etc/netplan/*.yaml look like this:**

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enx0000000006cd5a:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
  wifis:
    wlp1s0:
      addresses: [192.168.1.12/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 192.168.1.1]
      access-points:
        "network_ssid_name":
          password: "**********"
```

**You may have to install wpasupplicant:**

`sudo apt-get update` # update software databases

`sudo apt-get install wpasupplicant` # install wpasupplicant

**Netplan commands:**

`sudo netplan --debug generate` # generate config files

`sudo netplan apply` # apply new config

`reboot` # because of static IP